# get error message on $http.post request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, angularjs, web-services, iis-6

i get this error message:
'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**serve side :**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "user_login/", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
UserBase UserLogin(UserBase value);

public UserBase UserLogin(UserBase value)
{
    UserLogic UserLg = new UserLogic();
    value = UserLg.GetUser(value);
    return value;
}
```

**client side:**

```
var DTO = {
              user_email: "v@prova.it",
              user_pass: "v"
          }

          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $http.post(constants().user_login, DTO
               )
                  .success(function (d) {
                      data = d;
                      $timeout(function () {
                          $rootScope.$broadcast('userLoggedIn');
                      });
                      deferred.resolve(d);
                  })
                  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                  });
```

in local host everything works fine.
but after i upload the project to IIS in outer server i get the next error:
[image]
[image]

there, is nothing else to see after i opened fidler. i checked in the server logs and didn't find something interesting...
please help.

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Request Error</title>
    <style>BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white; font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content { margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366; border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre { font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family: Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;} table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid; background-color: #e5e5cc;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <p class="heading1">Request Error</p>
      <p>The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is: </p>
      <p>   at api.UserLogin(UserBase value)
   at SyncInvokeUserLogin(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
```

at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem
actually it was an error in the BL.